# getting values from particular row from html table and get as json array

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function scan() {
  const res = [...document.querySelectorAll("#stockinboundedittable tr")].slice(1).map(tr =>
    Object.fromEntries(
      [...tr.querySelectorAll("input")].slice(1).map(inp => [inp.id.replace(/.*inboundedit/, "").replace(/\d+$/, ""), inp.value])));

  document.getElementById("some").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(res);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table style="width:100%;   border-collapse: collapse;  text-align: center;" id="stockinboundedittable">
      
        <tr>
          <th style="display:none;">subcategory</th>
          <th>Sl.No</th>
          <!--<th>I.U.Code</th>-->
          <th>Item Name</th>
          <th> old stock</th>
          <th> new stock</th>
          <th> Total Stock</th>
          <th> qrt</th>
          <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
     
      <tr id="rowone">
        <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_2</td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound1" value="1" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname1" value="Fresh Goat Meat - Curry Cut" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock1" value="20" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock1" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock1" value="30" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty1">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut1">EDIT</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="rowtwo"> 
        <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_5</td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound2" value="2" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname2" value="Everest - Kasur Methi" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock2" value="0" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock2" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock2" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty2">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut2">EDIT</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="rowthree">
        <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_13</td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound3" value="3" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname3" value="Fresh Coconut Milk 150 ml" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock3" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock3" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock3" value="20" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty3">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut3">EDIT</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="rowfour">
        <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_5</td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound4" value="4" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname4" value="Sakthi - Chicken Masala" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock4" value="20" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock4" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock4" value="30" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty4">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut4">EDIT</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="rowfive">
        <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_2</td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound5" value="5" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname5" value="Goat Bones - Regular Soup Pack" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock5" value="0" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock5" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock5" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty5">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut5">EDIT</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      
    </table>
    <button onclick="scan()">Scan The Table</button>
    <button >getting row with id</button>
    <br><span id="some"></span>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### What I am doing

1. Here i have been getting values of whole Html table value using (Map)

### Example

| Item Name | old stock | new stock | Total Stock | qrt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fresh Goat Meat - Curry Cut | 20 | 10 | 30 |  |
| Everest - Kasur Methi | 0 | 10 | 10 |  |
| Fresh Coconut Milk 150 ml | 10 | 10 | 20 |  |
| Sakthi - Chicken Masala | 20 | 10 | 30 |  |
| Goat Bones - Regular Soup Pack | 0 | 10 | 10 |  |

### json array format

[{"itemname":"Fresh Goat Meat - Curry Cut","oldstock":"20","newstock":"10","totalstock":"30","qty":""},{"itemname":"Everest - Kasur Methi","oldstock":"0","newstock":"10","totalstock":"10","qty":""},{"itemname":"Fresh Coconut Milk 150 ml","oldstock":"10","newstock":"10","totalstock":"20","qty":""},{"itemname":"Sakthi - Chicken Masala","oldstock":"20","newstock":"10","totalstock":"30","qty":""},{"itemname":"Goat Bones - Regular Soup Pack","oldstock":"0","newstock":"10","totalstock":"10","qty":""}]

### Description

1.In The above table i sliced off first column( which has sl.no ) and sliced Off Edit button which in last column I have been only getting  tag values

### What Do i needed

1. I want to get value from second row( or any row) using ID (rowID) (rowtwo) as json array

ID=rowtwo

### Example

| Item Name | old stock | new stock | Total Stock | qrt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Everest - Kasur Methi | 0 | 10 | 10 |  |

### json array format

["itemname":"Everest - Kasur Methi","oldstock":"0","newstock":"10","totalstock":"10","qty":""}]

### Desceiption

1. I need to get only particular row with rowID instead of getting whole table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have all the logic necessary to achieve your goal, you simply need to provide a way to access it. In the following snippet I've split your existing `scan()` function into reusable utility functions: `object_from_row()` which accepts a `tr` element and returns an object based on your logic and `display_row_data()` which will display the row data in the DOM.

It is then just a matter of linking your `getting row with ID` button to the `object_from_row()` function. In the snippet I've replaced your button with a `select` and populated it with each `tr` in your table.

```
// populate row select
const row_select = document.getElementById('row-select');

const option_fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
document.querySelectorAll('#stockinboundedittable tr').forEach((tr) => {
  if (tr.id) {
    const opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = tr.id;
    opt.textContent = `Row ${tr.id.replace('row', '')}`;
    option_fragment.appendChild(opt);
  }
});
row_select.appendChild(option_fragment);
```

and defined a `get_row_data()` function which accepts an id and is triggered on `change` of the select.

```
function get_row_data(row_id) {
  const row = document.getElementById(row_id);

  const res = [object_from_row(row)];

  display_row_data(res);
}

row_select.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  get_row_data(e.target.value);
});
```

It should be noted that there is not JSON here, only javascript objects.

```js
// declare functions
function display_row_data(data) {
  document.getElementById('some').innerHTML = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(
    data,
    null,
    2,
  )}</pre>`;
}

function object_from_row(tr) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    [...tr.querySelectorAll('input')]
      .slice(1)
      .map((inp) => [
        inp.id.replace(/.*inboundedit/, '').replace(/\d+$/, ''),
        inp.value,
      ]),
  );
}

function scan() {
  const res = [...document.querySelectorAll('#stockinboundedittable tr')]
    .slice(1)
    .map(object_from_row);

  display_row_data(res);
}

function get_row_data(row_id) {
  const row = document.getElementById(row_id);

  const res = [object_from_row(row)];

  display_row_data(res);
}

// init functionality
const scan_button = document.getElementById('scan');
const row_select = document.getElementById('row-select');

// populate row select
const option_fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
document.querySelectorAll('#stockinboundedittable tr').forEach((tr) => {
  if (tr.id) {
    const opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = tr.id;
    opt.textContent = `Row ${tr.id.replace('row', '')}`;
    option_fragment.appendChild(opt);
  }
});
row_select.appendChild(option_fragment);

// attach listeners
scan_button.addEventListener('click', scan);

row_select.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  get_row_data(e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table style="width:100%;   border-collapse: collapse;  text-align: center;" id="stockinboundedittable">
      
        <tr>
          <th style="display:none;">subcategory</th>
          <th>Sl.No</th>
          <!--<th>I.U.Code</th>-->
          <th>Item Name</th>
          <th> old stock</th>
          <th> new stock</th>
          <th> Total Stock</th>
          <th> qrt</th>
          <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
     
      <tr id="rowone">
        <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_2</td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound1" value="1" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname1" value="Fresh Goat Meat - Curry Cut" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock1" value="20" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock1" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock1" value="30" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty1">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut1">EDIT</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="rowtwo"> 
        <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_5</td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound2" value="2" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname2" value="Everest - Kasur Methi" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock2" value="0" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock2" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock2" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty2">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut2">EDIT</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="rowthree">
        <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_13</td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound3" value="3" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname3" value="Fresh Coconut Milk 150 ml" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock3" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock3" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock3" value="20" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty3">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut3">EDIT</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="rowfour">
        <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_5</td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound4" value="4" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname4" value="Sakthi - Chicken Masala" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock4" value="20" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock4" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock4" value="30" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty4">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut4">EDIT</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="rowfive">
        <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_2</td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound5" value="5" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname5" value="Goat Bones - Regular Soup Pack" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock5" value="0" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock5" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock5" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty5">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut5">EDIT</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      
    </table>
    <button type="button" id="scan">Scan The Table</button>
    <select name="get-row" id="row-select">
      <option disabled selected value>Get row data</option>
    </select>
    <br><span id="some"></span>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```